# Elastic: How to search for document with specific url?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic search index with two fields `html` and `url` and the following mapping:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to retrieve documents by the url? For example I want the document where the url field **contains** `google.com`. The result might be the two documents with the urls `https://www.google.com` and `www.google.com/search`. I tried different queries but it seems not to work all the time.

```py
query = {
   "query" : {
      "match_phrase" : {
         "url" : f"google.com"
      }
    }
}

response = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
                es_client,
                index=my_index,
                doc_type="_doc",
                query=query
            )
```

Comment: Hey @Pascal, could you share your queries ?

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: Thnaks a lot, i think I have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR;

You should use the `keyword` field not the `text` field.

```
query = {
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "url.keyword" : f"google.com"
      }
    }
}

response = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es_client,
    index=my_index,
    doc_type="_doc",
    query=query)
```

But keep in mind this is going to do exact match, on `google.com`

## To reproduce

Create index and Add data

```
PUT /so_search_url/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /so_search_url/_doc
{
  "html": "<h1>Plop</h1>",
  "url": "https://www.google.com"
}

POST /so_search_url/_doc
{
  "html": "<h1>Plop</h1>",
  "url": "https://www.google.fr"
}

POST /so_search_url/_doc
{
  "html": "<h1>Plop</h1>",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/search"
}
```

Search the data for exact match

```
GET /so_search_url/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "url.keyword": "https://www.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Search the data for prefix match

```
GET /so_search_url/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "url.keyword": {
        "value": "https://www.google.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## To understand

> ...two new types: text, which should be used for full-text search, and keyword, which should be used for keyword search.

[[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out later. But if I'm understanding you correctly this will yield only exact matches. Am I right? If so how can I adapt to match fields containing the query string. In your example I would expect all entries except  `https://www.google.fr` to be returned, because they contain `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: That is a good question indeed, you want to use `prefix query` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html
I ll add it to my answer.